# Why can STL vector's iterator point to element which does not exist?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I write test code to find out whether an itrerator of vector can be beyond the end() iterator, like this.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(100);
    cout << v.capacity() << endl;
    vector<int>::iterator itr = v.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i, ++itr)
        if (itr == v.end()) cout << "end at " << i << endl;
    cout << *itr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

printed result:

```
1
end at 1
0
```

the vector object v has only 1 capacity, but its iterator can access the memory after the end() iterator. Is there any protection for this situation?

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, and the standard mandates no protection against this.

Comment: You mean besides *not* doing it?

Comment: Because it adds overhead for checking it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterators do not protect against accessing elements that aren't there, because they should guarantee minimal overhead. The same holds for [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at). Accessing an element at or beyond the [`std::vector::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) using one of these methods yields undefined behavior and there is no way to detect it after the fact.

However, the [`std::vector::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) member function throws an [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) in those cases. This exception can be caught and handled gracefully. Implementing this functionality for iterators would introduce runtime overhead because of bounds checking. It would also introduce space overhead, because the iterator would now not only need to know about the current element, but also about the vector that it iterates over.

Answer (score 1):

With vector access, the `capacity` property is less interesting than the `size`. The formet holds the internal buffer size and the latter holds the stored element count. Always `count <= capacity`.

With that said, vectors were designed to replace/upgrade C arrays so their design specifies implicitly the following:

- Locality: all items are stored in a single sequential buffer.
- Speed: in order to increase speed, no boundary checks are performed.

The latter is not true for **debug** versions that may implement boundary checking and iterator validation.

To iterate a vector us one of the following code snippets:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr) {
   int item = *itr;
...
}
```

Or

```
size_t size = v.size():
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
   int item = v[i];
...
}
```

**Note: both code snippets assume you do not add or remove items from the vector.**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your kindly answer, I know what you said. maybe I don't describe my idea properly. vector always maintain a memory block to store its elements, the iterator object _itr_ in my test code can access the memory outside the memory obtained by the vector object.

Comment: I upgraded the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of the standard library come with checked iterators for debug builds. These will emit diagnostic errors if you attempt to use them incorrectly.

I know that at least VS 2005+ (aka Dinkumware), STLport and libstdc++ can do this.